# Powershell Split 1 column into 2 columns

Tags: powershell, csv, split

Im familar with the -split operator and how to split a string, but i cant figure out how to split a string in one column and turn it into 2 seperate columns

Data:

```
"MPN","Item_Description","Customer_Order"
"000501","BLU 60MM Slate Shale Grey (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer)","12055"
"000501","BLU 60MM Slate Shale Grey (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer)","12421"
"000501","BLU 60MM Slate Shale Grey (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer)","12424"
"002243","Mini-Creta Architectural 6'' Champlain Grey (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer)","12014"
"002243","Mini-Creta Architectural 6'' Champlain Grey (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer)","12425"
"002243","Mini-Creta Architectural 6'' Champlain Grey (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer)","12817"
```

I am trying to figure out how to split or copy the data in between '(' and 'sqft/pallet' in the "Item_Description" column to its own column.

my biggest obstacle is splitting it and then adding it back in as a new column with a new header to look like this:

```
"MPN","Item_Description","Sqft_Pallet","Customer_Order"
"000501","BLU 60MM Slate Shale Grey (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer)","116.82","12055"
"000501","BLU 60MM Slate Shale Grey (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer)","116.82","12421"
"000501","BLU 60MM Slate Shale Grey (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer)","116.82","12424"
"002243","Mini-Creta Architectural 6'' Champlain Grey (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer)","30","12014"
"002243","Mini-Creta Architectural 6'' Champlain Grey (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer)","30","12425"
"002243","Mini-Creta Architectural 6'' Champlain Grey (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer)","30","12817"
```

Comment: What's your code so far ?

Comment: i have not been successful in my attempts. i believe i need to do a foreach loop on each row on the column and however its changed a bit form split to actually copy a string into a cew column

Comment: Why use a script, there's a CSV plugin for Notepad++ which has a split column option https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/ You can split on character `(` to create a new column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use calculated properties with `Select-Object`. This example assumes `Sqft_Pallet` is always fully contained in parentheses:

```
$CsvData | select MPN,
  Item_Description,
  @{l='Sqft_Pallet';e={
    # Regex is to select anything inside parentheses from Item_Description
    if ($_.Item_Description -match '\(.*\)') {$Matches.Values} 
    else {'N/A'}  ## if no full parentheses present, use N/A
  }},
  Customer_Order
```

Outputs like so:

```
MPN    Item_Description                                                           Sqft_Pallet                             Customer_Order
---    ----------------                                                           -----------                             --------------
000501 BLU 60MM Slate Shale Grey (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer)          (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer) 12055         
000501 BLU 60MM Slate Shale Grey (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer)          (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer) 12421         
000501 BLU 60MM Slate Shale Grey (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer)          (116.82 sqft/pallet - 10.62 sqft/layer) 12424         
002243 Mini-Creta Architectural 6' Champlain Grey (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer) (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer)         12014         
002243 Mini-Creta Architectural 6' Champlain Grey (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer) (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer)         12425         
002243 Mini-Creta Architectural 6' Champlain Grey (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer) (30 sqft/pallet - 6 sqft/layer)         12817         
002243 Mini-Creta Architectural 6' Champlain Grey 30 sqft/pal                     N/A                                     12817
```

Comment: awesome, i always struggle when it comes to regex. could you help me understand {$Matches.Values} i think i understand the rest of it. if i wanted to change the regex to be between '(' and 'sqft/pallet' would it look like this: '\(.*sqft\/pallet')

Comment: I have seen @{N or Name= but not {L what does the l stand for

Comment: @moore1emu See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#matches) to understand the `$matches` automatic varible. `L=` stands for `label=`, same use as `n=` or `name=`.